# responsive drop-down navigation bar

Tags: navigation, dropdown, responsive

I have a dropdown list in my navigation and I am trying to figure out how to change it with a media query at 845px. From my current codes, my dropdown list seems to go behind the background and I am also losing my first nav link of Home.

```
<nav class="center">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="drop">
<a href="cast.html" class="dropbut">The Cast<i class="fa fa-caret-down">
</i></a><div class="drop-list">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Bateman" 
target="_blank">Jason Bateman</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_McAdams" 
target="_blank">Rachel McAdams</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylie_Bunbury" 
target="_blank">Kylie Bunbury</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamorne_Morris" 
target="_blank">Lamorne Morris</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyle_Chandler" 
target="_blank">Kyle Chandler</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Plemons" 
target="_blank">Jesse Plemons</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Magnussen" 
target="_blank">Billy Magnussen</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharon_Horgan" 
target="_blank">Sharon Horgan</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Goldstein_(filmmaker)" 
target="_blank">Jonathan Goldstein- Director</a>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Francis_Daley" 
target="_blank">John Francis Daley- Director</a>
</div></li>
<li><a href="trailer_and_reviews.html">Take A Peek</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and CSS

```
/*responsive info*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 845px) {
nav {
display: flex;
position: relative;
z-index: 6;
}
li a .drop-list .dropbut {
display: none;
}

ul {
display: block;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
ul li {
width: 100%;
float: none;
}
}
```

I am very new to this and I now completely confused. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I [currently have](http://jsfiddle.net/68nn49z0/)

This is what [I want](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)